# Connect Quickbooks Online to SugarCRM using Talend

Tags: plugins, quickbooks, talend, quickbooks-online

I would like to migrate accounts and other transactions from SugarCRM to Quickbooks Online.

But I didn't find any talend plugins for QBO.

Any idea how I can accomplish this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does QuickBooks have an API at all?

Comment: Yes, that is online version of Quickbooks.

Comment: you have to use either rest or similar api() exposed by quickbooks and surgarcrm and write your own java code to syncup this. or you can prepare your own talend component, or there are providers in market who provide such kind of migration/integration services..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find some components from [cloudb](http://www.cloudb.com) and [qbo-connect.com](http://www.qbo-connect.com). I will have to choose cause they are paid plugins.